# how to zoom image specific part in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image on a canvas. I want to zoom the image to a specific part on left side. It will happen 10 secs after loading (the zooming also done slowly). How can I do that?

```
function draw()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var y = new Image();
    y.src = "images.jpg";
    ctx.drawImage(y,0,0,400,400);
}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this piece of code

```
ctx.scale(2, 2) // Doubles size of anything draw to canvas.
```

or look at this link http://www.akademy.co.uk/blog/2010/06/canvaszoom-html5-canvas-and-code/